# What's the default value of ConnectTimeout in connection string?

Tags: .net

If we dont set the ConnectTimeout value, e.g. "Connect Timeout=60", (neither in SqlCommand), what's the dafault value it will be? I was told it's 15s

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [default connection timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in [SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) is **15 seconds**.

Answer (score 13):

From the [`SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx):

> The time (in seconds) to wait for a connection to open. The default value is 15 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Your've been told correctly. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) is the proof

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's 30 seconds, default on MS SQL Server

EDIT: as others have corrected me, 15 seconds is the default.

Doh, my bad! apologies!